# [C++]: Refactoring away deprecated covariant return type warning

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, gcc-warning

So, a while back, I wrote a library that included some template classes that look like this:

```
class baseClass {
    public:
        virtual void * getIndex(int index);
};

template <class T>
class myClass : baseClass {
    public:
        T * getIndex(int index);
};
```

And then created a specialized version of `getIndex` for `int`:

```
template <> int * myClass<int>::getIndex(int index) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This yields the following compiler warning under `gcc` 4.7.2:

```
warning: deprecated covariant return type for 'T* myClass<T>::getIndex(int) [with T = int]' [enabled by default]
```

Now, I normally wouldn't care about this very much, but it's recently become critical that I perform a Mac port of my library, and `gcc` on the Mac is much stricter about this. Beyond that, it's something I would like to eliminate anyways (code smell and all that).

My need is twofold: I must retain both `baseClass` (and `myClass`'s derivation from `baseClass`) and a specialized version of `myClass` for `int` (or something that behaves 100% identically to `int`), but the latter must not rely on deprecated behaviour. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I've already considered writing a wrapper class for `int` (as seen in Java), but that would be a maintenance headache in and of itself that I'd rather avoid if possible (especially since I'd also need to do it for `float` and `char` in my current implementation). Is there a better solution? Or an existing library that wraps the C++ primitives?

Comment: There isn't enough code there to reproduce the warning, even if `// Do stuff` is
replaced with some compilable filler. Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Didn't realize that `baseClass` was important to the problem.